# Application Insights log4j appender does not exit

Tags: scala, log4j, azure-application-insights, appender

I've been trying to push my scala console application's logs to Application Insights using Application Insights log4j v1.2 appender. It is working as expected, but at the end, the application is not exiting. Is there any connection that I need to close for the application to exit? Can someone please help me with this issue? I cannot use `System.exit(0)` or `Thread.interrupt()` because this will cause my Spark application to fail on cluster.

Below is my source code:

AILogger.scala:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{ Logger, Level, MDC }
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v1_2.ApplicationInsightsAppender

object AILogger {
  var rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
  var ai = new ApplicationInsightsAppender()
  ai.setInstrumentationKey("Insert IKey here")
  ai.activateOptions()


  @transient lazy val logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass)
  logger.setLevel(Level.INFO)
  rootLogger.addAppender(ai)
  rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  def info(message: String): Unit = {
    logger.info(message)
  }
}
```

AILoggerTest.scala:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

object AILoggerTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    AILogger.info("logging to AI " + LocalDateTime.now())
    System.out.println("Completed")      
  }
}
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I believe it is a matter of some ThreadPools still working. With JavaEE apps something like https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/blob/40809cb6857231e572309a5901e1227305c27c1a/core/src/main/java/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/internal/shutdown/SDKShutdownActivity.java would probably we autowired, with any application not relying on such magic you would probably turn off these threads yourself. Check if manually calling stopAll() would help.

Comment: How can I call `stopAll()` method. It is inside the `SDKShutdownActivity` enum's class?

Comment: This single-value enum is one of ways Java programmers implement singleton. `SDKShutdownActivity.INSTANCE.stopAll()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaEE/Spring MVC applications autowire ThreadPool shutdowns. In your case you have to trigger it yourself when application is supposed to exit:

```
SDKShutdownActivity.INSTANCE.stopAll()
```